# How to use dynamic list name?

Tags: c#

```
p1.Contains(listname[i, 0]);

p2.Contains(listname[i, 0]);
```

is there a way to replace p1 and p2 and use an variable instead.
I want to do something like

```
"p" + variableName.Contains(listname[i, 0]);
```

This doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how I can make this work?

Comment: Give us the bigger picture: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is far from obvious what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to reference local variables by a string representation of their "name", you are probably better off storing your lists in a `Dictionary<string, List<YourType>>`.

Comment: @klaus it is obvious, it is the umpteenth question about variable variables as they exist in PHP: `$foo = 'p'; $bar = 1; $myVar = ${$foo$bar}` (or something like that), gaining the result of the variable named `$p1`. As with all previous instances of this question, the answer is "use an array, dictionary or other collection that suits your needs".

Comment: Read: [*evaluating-string-variable-name*](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/279029-evaluating-string-variable-name)

Comment: @CodeCaster how come no one is giving the *real* answer to the question then: **Use reflection!** :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use an array or a hash table.

```
var p = new ICollection[2];
p[0] = p0;
p[1] = p1;
...
p[your_variable].Contains(listname[i,0]);
```

You cannot access variables by their names, as their names do not persist in runtime, e.g. the CLR has no chance to find the value of a variable "p1".

Answer (score 1):

You can make array of p instead of declaring multiple variable. Assuming `p1` and `p2` are strings.

```
P []p = new P[10];

for(int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
     p[i].Contains(listname[i, 0]
```

It would be better if you can use List

```
List<P> p = new List<P>();

for(int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
   p[i].Contains(listname[i, 0]
```

**Edit** base on comments, `p1` and `p2` are collections

```
 var p = new ICollection[2];
 List<P> p1 = new List<P>();
 List<P> p2 = new List<P>();
 p[0] = p1;
 p[1] = p2;

p[variableContainZeroOrOne].Contains(listname[i, 0]
```

Comment: I have one variable that changes with every turn 1-2 and 2-1 isn't it possible to put it like "p" + variableName.

Comment: You better replace variable with array

Comment: @user3305851 No. That is not possible.

Comment: The list method isnt working for me.

Comment: Not working does gives any clue what is the problem, can you tell what exactly happening?

Comment: I have two differents lists one for p1 and other for p2 p1.add(12) and p2.add(11) what i want to do is p[variable].add(value) the variable should tell to what list to add.

Comment: Why dont you put condition on variable if(variable == someval) p1.add... else p2.add

Comment: Wanted to know if it was possible to do it directly since the variable keeps changing xD

Comment: Look at Georg, that is the closest to what you want

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes the list as a parameter.

```
public bool doSomething (List list, int i)
{
    bool test = list.Contains(listname[i, 0]);
    return test;
}
```

Comment: You should explain that he has to create a new List, and add  his `p1`, `p2`, `p3` to that new list.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a variable of type List and assign the correct list to it. Use this variable in the rest of your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables `p1`, `p2` and you want to *reference* them by using number, then:

Solution 1, create helper method

```
string PX(int number)
{
   switch(number)
   {
       case 1: return p1;
       case 2: return p2;
   }

   // or
   if(number == 1) return p1;
   if(number == 2) return p2;
}

// usage
PX(x).Contains(blablabla);
```

Solution 2, use indexes

```
// helper array
string[] px = new string[] {p1, p2};
// usage
px[i - 1].Contains(blablabla);
```

or

```
// helper array
string[] px = new string[] {null, p1, p2};
// usage
px[i].Contains(blablabla);
```

Solution 3, use key-value collections.

Solution 4, use reflection.

Solutions 3 and 4 are slower and with unnecessary overhead. Indexes are fast, having helper method or helper array is not too much, consider following when constructing properties

```
private string[] _px = string[2];
public string[] PX { get { return px; } }
public string P1
{
    get { return _px[0]; }
    set { _px[0] = value; }
}
public string P2
{
    get { return _px[1]; }
    set { _px[1] = value; }
}
```

This way data are initially saved in array = you don't waste memory, while having possibility to access values by index `PX[index]` or by name `P1`/`P2`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Lists?

Comment: replace `string` with `List` (i took `string`, because I know `string.Contains` method)

Comment: I have two differents lists one for p1 and other for p2 p1.add(12) and p2.add(11) what i want to do is p[variable].add(value) the variable should tell to what list to add.

Comment: If variable >= 0 and <= array length - 1, then you are fine to just have array of lists `List[] px = new List[] {p1, p2}`, so `px[0] == p1` and `px[1] == p2`.

Comment: Does that make two seperate lists where values get stored depending on the variable?

Comment: If you want to *reference* N different `List`s, then the best is to initially have them in N-sized array and use index. Instead of `p1` you will have to use `px[0]` anywhere in your code. If `p1` and `p2` are different lists, then `px = new List[] {p1, p2}` is an array of 2 lists indeed. `px` is not a **copy** of your array, it's just an array. To make it simple, `px` will take something like 8 bytes of memory *disregards* how big `p1` or `p2` are.

Comment: I have one more question is it possible to make the list public/global?

Comment: Try it. Or better read a book about `C#` first! This way you will have hundreds of future questions answered! And if you are going to ask `which book?`, then go google and type there something like `c# best book`!